# trying to download specific files from ftp recursively and run a command on them

Tags: windows, powershell, ftp, cmd

i'm trying to download every file with a certain file name from an ftp location, run a command on it then delete it.

ex: download every file that looks like "*_qwerty.jpeg" from "\some\random\ftp\location" then run a command on it. once command is finished, delete it. i need the script to ignore all other.jpeg files too.

i'm trying to do this in windows CMD or Powershell

does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What code have you come up with? What command do you want to run on it? Is it a native PowerShell command, or a script? What you ask doesn't sound hard, but with more information it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use Ftp.exe and drive it with a parameter file. Use mget to download files with wildcards. Iterate the files with foreach loop and do stuff. Like so,

```
<commandfile>
lcd <path-to-local-dir>
open <ftp-site>
<username>
<password>
bin
cd <path-to-remote-dir>
prompt
mget <filename-with-wildcards>
close
bye
```

Using the command file in Powershell is simple enough:

```
Ftp -s:<commandfile>
foreach($i in gci <path-to-images>) {
  <do-something> $i
}
```

You could do the same with batch scripting as well (remember to use double-% in script, single % in command line).

```
Ftp -s:<commandfile>
for /f "tokens=*" %j in ('dir /b <path-to-images') do <do-something> %j
```

Comment: my next question is the <path to images> part. would i enter the local path or the ftp? if it's the ftp, how would i enter that?

Comment: i tried just running the "ftp -s:" part. it accepts all the parameters from the command file but returns the following message "Cannot find list of remote files." the files are stored in different subdirectories in that location. could that be the issue?

Comment: <path-to-images> refers, of course, to the local directory FTP saves the images.